# Swift 3 code update

Tags: json, swift, syntax

```
class SignUp: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonNameTxt: UITextField! @IBOutlet weak var buttonEmailTxt: UITextField! @IBOutlet weak var buttonPwdTxt: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func buttonSignIn(_ sender: UIButton){

        let usermainname:NSString = buttonNameTxt.text! as NSString let username:NSString = buttonEmailTxt.text! as NSString let password:NSString = buttonPwdTxt.text! as NSString

        let myURL = NSURL(string: "https:\mev.com/api/login")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myURL as! URL) request.httpMethod = "Post"

        let postString = "name = (usermainname) email = (username) &passwod = (password) " request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data , response , error in

            do {

                let err: NSError? let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                print(json as Any)

                if let parseJSON = json { let resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String print ("result:(resultValue)")

                    var isUserRegister:Bool = false if resultValue == "success" {isUserRegister = true}

                    var messageToDisplay:String = parseJSON["massage"] as! String if isUserRegister {

                        messageToDisplay = parseJSON["massage"] as! String

                    }

                }

            } catch {

                print("error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is error

> 2016-11-16 12:37:16.328505 MevicsPromo[12011:692688] [MC] System
>   group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path
>   is
>   /Users/HardBuf/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E3B4C6A4-A49D-4363-89D5-31931EA513A8/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   2016-11-16 12:37:16.328782 MevicsPromo[12011:692688] [MC] Reading from
>   private effective user settings. 2016-11-16 12:37:18.276331
>   MevicsPromo[12011:692798] 0x60000014e4f0 Copy matching assets reply:
>   XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0,
>   contents = "Result" => : 29 } 2016-11-16 12:37:18.277030
>   MevicsPromo[12011:692798] 0x608000357b80 Daemon configuration query
>   reply: XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY { count = 2, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0,
>   contents = "Dictionary" => { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0,
>   contents = "ServerURL" => { count = 3, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0,
>   contents = "com.apple.CFURL.magic" =>
>   C3853DCC-9776-4114-B6C1-FD9F51944A6D "com.apple.CFURL.string" => {
>   length = 30, contents = "https:\mesu.apple.com/assets/" }
>   "com.apple.CFURL.base" => : null-object } } "Result" => : 0 }
>   2016-11-16 12:37:18.277318 MevicsPromo[12011:692798]
>   http:\ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help[MobileAssetError:29] Unable to
>   copy asset information from https:\mesu.apple.com/assets/ for asset
>   type com.apple.MobileAsset.TextInput.SpellChecker

Comment: What is your question? Please format your question and  learn [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is this error and how fix it?
Or maybe i do something not properly?

Comment: @KonstantinOvcharenko Please read the [tour] and the [help]. You need to learn how to format your code properly and how to ask a good question that's within Stack's guidelines. Thanks.

Comment: @KonstantinOvcharenko, they mean that context information is missing. Questions here stand for many languages, on diverse platforms, for different problems, and so on. Infinite scenarios. Nobody can guess what are you trying to do without a *clear* explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your code using Swift 3 syntax.

```
class SignUp: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var buttonNameTxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonEmailTxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonPwdTxt: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func buttonSignIn(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let usermainname = buttonNameTxt.text!
    let username = buttonEmailTxt.text!
    let password = buttonPwdTxt.text!

    let myURL = URL(string: "https://mev.com/api/login")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myURL!)
    request.httpMethod = "Post"

    let postString = "name = \(usermainname) email = \(username) &passwod = \(password)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data , response , error in

        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {

                let resultValue = json["status"] as? String
                print("result: \(resultValue)")

                if resultValue == "success", let messageToDisplay = json["massage"] as? String {
                    print("\(messageToDisplay)")
                }
            }

        } catch {

            print("error")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
If you can help me, please, take example how can it be realization?
I need registration and authorization on app. 
I have api https://mev.com/api/login and all JSON what need for registration. 
Я вас нашел в фейсбуке и написал все на русском ибо знаю, что мой английский оставляет желать лучшего, буду очень благодарен за помощь

Comment: You are welcome) Please mark answer. 
You are talking about registration your app to use api mev.com ?

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял, то да, мне нужно сделать регистрацию используя  api mev.com